# How do I fix my camera on my iphone 4?

Tags: camera

My camera on my iPhone 4 is showing nothing but a black screen. Front and rear camera and it happens in all camera related apps as well. When I reset my phone it fixes it, but the problem keeps reoccurring. How do I permanently fix the problem?

Comment: you have a app that is interfering with it.

Comment: would it be any app or camera apps only?

Comment: any app that uses (or can use) camera/video calling...you need to find out which one, by turning them off (or uninstalling)

Answer (score 1):

Is the phone jailbroken? If so, try running it not jailbroken for a while to see if the problem reoccurs.

Other than that, try an OS restore - just make sure you do a backup first.